# Codeigniter controller not accessible without index.php in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've tried going over similar questions asked here before and tried out couple of solutions, however, they doesn't seem to work.

I have a folder called "projectX" in my `localhost` **root** directory which is a **CodeIgniter project**

This project has a controller called dashboard.

The dashboard is accessible by going through this link http://localhost/projectX/index.php/dashboard

However, if I try to do it **without** `index.php` (http://localhost/projectX/dashboard) it says Not Found.

Here's what my .htaccess file looks like (the file is outside application folder and in root directory of projectX folder)

```
RewriteBase /projectX

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Here's my config file :-

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/projectX/";
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using ubuntu you should active rewrite mode "sudo a2enmod rewrite"

Comment: @sparshturkane
I'm on a mac.

Comment: Have you restarted apache ?

Comment: Just did. Nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Check these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And Change this also:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"

//  Replace with

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Source: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Comment: Try to keep .htaccess inside the root folder. It will work.

Comment: @NetStack Check updated answer and try to run again.

Comment: try to keep index.php and .htaccess in same folder location.

Comment: Check your Apache config file (httpd.conf) and check that your directory has AllowOverride option selected.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your .htaccess file

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```